How to use cppcheck binary created from rules_foreign_cc cmake in bazle build
I am trying to use cppcheck inside bazel.  So far I am able to build it with:
cmake(
    name = "cppcheck",
    build_args = [
        "-j16",
    ],
    lib_source = "@cppcheck//:all_srcs",
    out_binaries = ["cppcheck"],
    out_data_dirs = ["share"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
       target_compatible_with = [
      "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
   ],
)

My question is - how do I now use the executable cppcheck from within bazel?  It searches for the config files in the bazel cache, for example:

The Cppcheck binary was compiled with FILESDIR set to "/home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cad083bdffdce30d3898da89ee167cf3/sandbox/processwrapper-sandbox/11/execroot/_main/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/bzl/thirdparty/cppcheck/cppcheck/share/Cppcheck" and will therefore search for std.cfg in /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/cad083bdffdce30d3898da89ee167cf3/sandbox/processwrapper-sandbox/11/execroot/_main/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/bzl/thirdparty/cppcheck/cppcheck/share/Cppcheck/cfg.

I don't see how a person then gets at cppcheck from within the same bazel build.
